# Flag: update link to processed via JS

Tags: 7, flags

I'm using flag module to flags my nodes. Now, in frontpage the list of nodes (html) is get and put in the main DIV via AJAX,  so the flag module has not parsed these nodes. How can I say to flag module to re-get and process all flag link ? I know that I need to insert the call in my AJAX .get() function, but which is the correct flag-JS-function to call ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You probably should run `Drupal.attachBehaviors($('.newcontent'));` instead of trying to add this logic manually for each module. But since you asked for flag 3.x it is `Drupal.behaviors.flagLink.attach($('.newcontent'));`

Comment: Andre-B: thanks. It works without $('.newcontent') too.

Comment: yea, that will trigger the attachBehaviors again on all elements I guess..